# Отображение текста в sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Пытаюсь отобразить текст в sfml:

```
std::vector<sf::Text> npc_text(12);
if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            dot[i] = sf::CircleShape(3);
            npc_text[i / 5].setString(std::to_string(i));
            npc_text[i / 5].setPosition(x1 + Window.getSize().x / 2, y1 + Window.getSize().y / 2);
            npc_text[i / 5].setColor(sf::Color::Black);
            npc_text[i / 5].setCharacterSize(24);
        }
while (Window.isOpen())
    {
for (auto& text : npc_text)
        {
            Window.draw(text);
        }
}
```

Его почему-то не видно. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны также загрузить шрифт, и установить его для текста.

```
sf::Font font;//Должен жить всё время, пока нужен
if (!font.loadFromFile("my_font.ttf")){
   //error
}
//...
npc_text[i / 5].setFont(font);//Внутри сохраняется указатель на объект font
```

Comment: Когда так пытаюсь выдает ошибку:Failed to load font "my_font.ttf"

Comment: ну так сам шрифт-то есть?

Comment: my_font.ttf - это просто для примера

Comment: да. к exe кинул

Comment: попробуйте другой шрифт. Например: https://fontlibrary.org/ru/font/orkney 

Попробовал, Orkney Regular.ttf загружается без проблем.
И учтите, что относительные пути "отсчитываются" от рабочей директории, а не от той, где лежит exe (в некоторых ide рабочая директория и та, где лежит exe - отличаются).

Comment: спасибо)помогло)